# Any websites to hire a UX designer?

Tags: jobs, hiring

I am a programmer developing a small web app. Are there any good websites from where I can hire a UX designer to design my website? Quick google search gives me this for example:
http://www.freelanced.com/?a=88&k=ux+designers&n=1&t=2

Comment: I'd probably steer away from encouraging people to bid on your project (feels a little too much like crowdsourcing). Kenn's answer is great.

Comment: It depends whether you want somebody who's in the same country / culture to you.   I'd go for same culture, if not the same country.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite of all... Cameron Moll does a great job at http://www.authenticjobs.com.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I've had some luck, but nothing is better than a referral network.

- http://linkedin.com
- http://www.ixda.com
- http://www.behance.net
- http://www.coroflot.com

If you're bottom feeding: http://www.99designs.com - not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed, no one mentioned [dribbble](http://www.dribbble.com), [forrst](http://www.forrst.com). I'am UX designer myself and these two apart from behance are great source for viewing the work of some of the great designers.

Answer (score 0):

odesk.com, guru.com, elance.com , freelancer.com, getafreelancer.com

Comment: Most of those involve public bidding rather then applying for a job. The focus on cost rather then on quality is what keeps the web from moving forward and good work being produced.